# Double encoded url being fully decoded in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, urlencode

I have just come across something that is quite strange and yet I haven't found any mention on the interwebs of others having the same problem.

If I hit my ASP.NET application with a double encoded url then the `Request["myQueryParam"]` will do a double decode of the query for me. This is not desirable as I have double encoded my query string for a good reason.

Can others confirm I'm not doing something obviously wrong, and why this would happen. A solution to prevent it, without doing some nasty query string parsing, would be great too!

As an example if you hit the url: 
http://localhost/MyApp?originalUrl=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fAction%2fRedirect%3fUrl%3d%252fsomeUrl%253futm_medium%253dabc%2526utm_source%253dabc%2526utm_campaign%253dabc

(For reference %25 is the % symbol)

Then look at the `Request["originalUrl"]` (page or controller) the string returned is:

http://localhost/Action/Redirect?Url=/someUrl?utm_medium=abc&utm_source=abc&utm_campaign=abc

I would expect:

http://localhost/Action/Redirect?Url=%2fsomeUrl%3futm_medium%3dabc%26utm_source%3dabc%26utm_campaign%3dabc

I have also checked in Fiddler and the URL is being passed to the server correctly (one possible culprit could have been the browser decoding the URL before sending).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relax, the handling of encoded parameters by HttpRequest is not broken.

In fact, both as a hyperlink and a direct navigation from address bar result in your 'expected' result in the Request.

```
<a href="WebForm1.aspx?originalUrl=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fAction%2fRedirect%3fUrl%3d%252fsomeUrl%253futm_medium%253dabc%2526utm_source%253dabc%2526utm_campaign%253dabc">HEY</a>
```

and

```
WebForm1.aspx?originalUrl=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fAction%2fRedirect%3fUrl%3d%252fsomeUrl%253futm_medium%253dabc%2526utm_source%253dabc%2526utm_campaign%253dabc
```

result:
    http://localhost/Action/Redirect?Url=%2fsomeUrl%3futm_medium%3dabc%26utm_source%3dabc%26utm_campaign%3dabc

You must be doing something with the URL beforehand, like redirecting or stuffing a NavigateUrl property of an asp.net control and letting asp.net render it which might be performing the first decode before it hits the target page.

Comment: Ahhh, cheers, it seems to be cause by something related to our platform - quite possibly our URL rewriter. I'll make sure I test on an empty project first next time!

Comment: Yes it was our URL rewriter - we were accessing the QueryString property of the request and then appending it onto the rewritten URL without re-encoding. Thanks for the lead, once I had that it didn't take long to narrow it down.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you fixed it? I think I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with your browser.

Looking at [Google's Browser Security Document](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part1), the following browsers translate non-reserved %nn sequences in the address bar: MSIE7, MSIE8, FF3, Opera, Chrome.

In which browsers have you tested this outcome?

Comment: I thought the same, so I fired up Fiddler and confirmed that the browser was in fact sending the correct URL to the server (tested in FF3).